# How to Solve Error "object is not a matrix" in fitted(arima_model) when constructing Arima(0,0,0) White Noise

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

So, here i have a reproducible example on why getting this error:

**[Time Series Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qazuS.png)**

```
data = c(48,148,284,72,48,24,48,24,48,24,24,0,96,24,48,96,72,24,96,24,48)
time = ts(data, start=c(2015,2), end=c(2016,10), frequency=12)
```

i am trying to construct this time series into Arima Model, auto.arima recommend me Arima(0,0,0) to this time series data which is white noise, but after successfully created the model, the error begin when i try to extract the fitted value of model

**[Error in getting fitted model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYWOm.png)**

```
model = arima(time,order=c(0,0,0))
fitted(model)
```

I didn't understand what is the meaning of this error, because of this, i try using another time series data which is AirPassengers to make sure it can get the fitted value, here is the AirPassengers data i using

**[Data AirPassengers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sspw4.png)**

```
Y= window(AirPassengers, start=c(1949,7), end=c(1950,10))
model2 = arima(Y, order=c(0,0,0))
fitted(model2)
```

Again then i try to create same Arima model and try to get the fitted value of the model, and it worked flawlessly without any trace of error like this

**[Successfully get fitted value of AirPassengers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asgBg.png)**

with knowing these 2 example, i can't figure out why the first model are getting Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) object is not a matrix,
anyone can give me a clue/explanation ? is there something i missing or is this some bug?

also i noticed there is a little different from the summary model of the 2 model above like this:

**[Summary Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejxh8.png)**

```
summary(model)
summary(model2)
```

Thank You for noticing my question, any feedback welcomed :)

Comment: Pictures of data or code are not appreciated. Please copy these into your question as actual text and use the code markup tool on top of the edit window.

Comment: I wonder if I woke up in an alternative universe. Does not copy/paste exist here?

Comment: so sorry about it, i am still getting used to posting, above i already give actual text, thankyou for the correction sir @Roland, but you can see the pictures to see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad your question was so poorly stated, because I think it actually is pretty interesting, and someone more knowledgeable than me should probably be answering it.
I've been prodding functions, methods and namespaces for hours now, and it turns out to be a case of name masking/conflict/scoping, I think. (I'm not a computer scientist, I don't know all the words and all the things)

The fix is easy enough, you just use `Arima()` instead of `arima()`, or use `auto.arima()` directly.

```
library(forecast)

model.ARIMA <- Arima(time, order=c(0,0,0))
fitted(model.ARIMA)

# or
fitted(auto.arima(time))
```

The reason for this working is that `Arima()` returns an object with both the original time series and the fitted values already included. `fitted()` then simply returns `model.ARIMA$fitted`.

`arima()` on the other hand doesn't include the fitted values in the returned object, so `fitted()` will have to compute them. That is simple enough, you just subtract the the residuals from the original time series. Only trouble is that while the residuals are included in the model object, the original time series isn't, so some tricks need to be applied. What happens is that `fitted()` calls another function `getResponse()`, which searches the environment for an object with the name included in the model object (`model.ARIMA$series`), in your case `time`. Problems occur because `time` already existed before you created it, namely as the function `time()`. Normally that isn't such an issue, because R tends to understand when you want the variable and when you want the function, e.g:

```
c <- 4
c
c(1, c)
c <- base::c
c
```

Inside `getResponse()` however, evaluation is done differently, but I'm not entirely sure how.

The lesson is the same however: if you name your variable the same as a function, strange things can happen.

Comment: wow thanks @AkselA a great discovery indeed, so now i know what is the difference between Arima() and arima(), but so sorry i can't vote you, my reputation seems just too low, i am still new on stackoverflow, i bet other who came here will vote for you

Comment: No worry, that's just how it is.